# Shader files not opening in Xcode

Tags: opengl, glsl, xcode4.5, shader

My shader setup file is failing to open my .vert and .frag files for compiling and linking in XCode.

What steps do I need to take for my setup file to recognize the shader files in XCode 4.5.1?

Comment: In what world does XCode compile and link GLSL shaders? There is no Clang GLSL front-end that I am aware of... this has always been a task for the actual OpenGL implementation or translation layers like Cg or ANGLE.

Comment: XCode doesn't do it for you. I have a C code to handle it but was wondering why the shader files were not being identified by this code? http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/loading.php

Comment: Okay, so this is a very different question then, it really has nothing to do with XCode. But we will not be able to help you without some more detailed error information (e.g. program/shader info log output) and sample code.

Comment: No, it has to do with XCode. I'm not worried about the actual compilation and linking of the files. I'm wondering why, when I call fd = open(name, O_RDONLY) I'm getting -1.  .frag and .vert files are in the same directory as this code. Do I need to do more to have XCode build properly?

Comment: @Riftus: XCode is a development API. Anything happening at your programs runtime has **nothing** to do with XCode, and no setting in XCode will make that error go away. It also doesn't matter where the `.glsl` files are in relation to your source code. All that matters is, where the shader files are in relation to your programs so called *working directory* which is something very dynamic and can't be predicted. Either hardcode your paths to very well known places, or figure out the location of your binary at runtime and build a proper loading path using that information.

Comment: @Riftus: Since I just learnt that the umbrella project that created binreloc went defunct, and binreloc itself is in the public domain, I took the liberty of assuming maintainer status for this thing: https://github.com/datenwolf/binreloc

Answer (score 1):

1. open Build Phases
2. click top-left "+" button
3. select "Copy bundle Resources.." item,
4. add glsl file.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the suffix to ".glsl". If that doesn't work, you can always tell Xcode what type of files they are by selecting "OpenGL Shading Language Source" from the "File Type" popup in the File Inspector of the Utilities pane.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your problem. It looks like you're saying that at runtime, when you open the file, opening it fails? If so, then that has nothing to do with Xcode. How is your app packaged? Where did you put the shader files? Why are you using `open()` instead of getting them from your bundle's resources using `NSBundle` routines?

Comment: Because it's not an app. I'm just using XCode to quickly build and run simple opengl applications. The shader files are in the same directory as the file the opens/compiles/links them.

Comment: @Riftus: There's probably a project setting in XCode to set the current working directory under those circumstances. The only time I've used the XCode IDE was to simplify bundling .app programs, I use a Makefile and the commandline toolchain for the sort of stuff you're doing. I think that's kind of what Apple expects, they don't make the XCode IDE very friendly for non-app developers :P

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. You say, "Because it's not an app," but then say, "run simple opengl applications". You'll need to explain what you mean by "not an app," but "an application", as those are the same thing.

Comment: "App is short for application software but is frequently used to mean mobile app" - Wikipedia. I'm using it to run non-mobile applications. I'm not using cocoa.

Comment: @Riftus: The only problem with that description is that on the OS X platform, software can be bundled into ".app" packages. These are programs you can double click on in Finder and run, they contain the binary, most run-time resources, non-standard frameworks, etc. So in the context of OS X, "app" does not mean applet or anything of the sort. It gets even more confusing if you add iOS to the discussion, because they also use the ".app" bundle for things you really legitimately would call mobile apps. Considering OS X has an App store, it's safe to say any ".app" bundle can be called an app.

Comment: OK, so you're application packaging is not bundled. That's fine. The question then is where the application is being built to and where the shader files are going. In Xcode, if you right-click on the build product (your application) in the Project Navigator and choose "Reveal In Finder" is it in the same directory as your shader files? If not, you can add a Copy Files build phase to your project to copy them there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply place the shader files in the same file as the executable... DerivedData/projectName/Build/Products/Debug

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. In Xcode, click on your project name.
2. Navigate to Build Phases.
3. Under 'Copy Files', set the destination to 'Products Directory'.
4. Leave subpath blank.
5. Add your .frag and .vert files using the +

Answer (score 0):

So I was trying to copy some frag files and they would also fail to open.

1. Check that the files (.vert or .frag) in the xcodeproj's window are actually in your directory by right clicking and "show in finder"
2. In Xcode, click on your project name and Navigate to Build Phases.
3. Click on the ‘+’ symbol at the upper left corner and add a New Copy Files Phase
4. Make sure ‘Resources’ is selected, ‘Subpath’ is empty and ‘Copy only when installing’ is unchecked.
5. Then drag-and-drop files (.vert or .frag) one by one from the project navigator into the "Copy Files" under name.
6. Hopefully you can run the project

Steps 2 - 6 are summarised from a University of Wollongong (Australia) manual :)